# AndroidでLombokを使用してビルドエラーが発生しました。

Tags: java, android

今あるLombokを使っているAndroidプロジェクトに参加して、プロジェクトをビルドしたらエラーが出ました。

調べたこと：build.gradleにannotationProcessor... とか入れていない。

しかしプロジェクトを見たら入っていると分かりました（バージョンも古くはない）：

```
    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
```

ビルドして出てきたエラーは以下：

```
エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
    @Value @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
     ^
  シンボル:   クラス Value
  場所: クラス ....
```

```
エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
    @Value @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
            ^
  シンボル:   クラス AllArgsConstructor
  場所: クラス
```

少し気になるところ:コードの場所はルートパッケージの直下ではなくルートパッケージの下にまたパッケージを作ってコードを入れているようです。

例：
project id : com.sample.sam
java file : com/sample/sam/mypkg/logic.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は分からないですが、JDKのバージョンを1.8から11に変更したら直せました。